# Why do I keep seeing this equation in different fields?

Tags: mathematical-modeling, applications

I am a student studying mathematics at university. I have come across the expression $$1-\dfrac{1}{x}$$ in several different classes and I'm wondering about its significance.

The first place that I noticed it was in mathematical biology studies, where the percent of a population that needs to be vaccinated to induce herd immunity is given the formula, where $x$, in this case, is called the basic reproduction number, $R_0$.

The second place that I have noticed it is in Electricity and Magnetism, where surface charge densities are related by the above equation, and $x$, in that case, is $K$, the dielectric constant of a material.

I remembered [this Numberphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sj8Sg8qnjOg&t=790s), where they use an equation of a similar form $\left(x = 1+\frac{1}{x}\right)$ to find the golden ratio, which makes me this that somehow the first equation is related to the golden ratio, but I'mt not sure if that is correct. Why does this same formula appear in two seemingly unrelated fields? What makes it so relevant and (presumably) useful?

Comment: I think that it is just such a simple expression that it tends to pop up from time to time. Other simple expressions occur frequently also. I don't know of a deeper explanation than that.

Comment: That's not an equation, that's an expression. An equation has a "$=$" sign somewhere in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting as $\dfrac{x-1}x$, this is a ratio of two quantities, one being a "modified" version of the other. More generally,

$$\frac{a\pm b}{a}=1\pm\frac ba$$ expresses a *relative* change.

---

Regarding the Golden Ratio, we can remark that it is the limit of the ratio of successive Fibonacci numbers,

$$\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}=\frac{F_n+F_{n-1}}{F_n}=1+\frac1{\dfrac{F_n}{F_{n-1}}},$$ which explains the relation

$$\phi=1+\frac1\phi.$$

Comment: I do think, a quadratic equation $x^2=1+x$ is a much easier way to see how the recurrence works (without proving its convergence of course)

Comment: @YuriyS: maybe, but this quadratic equation is "coming out of the blue", and in no way related to a ratio.

Comment: @YuriyS: did you read my answer at all ?

Comment: @\YvesDaoust, I did, and I even upvoted it. I liked the answer, I just offered a different take on the last part

Comment: @YuriyS: for this to be understandable for the OP, you should recall the geometric definition of the Golden ratio, which indeed explains $a/b=b/(a+b)$. Without this, $x^2=x+1$ is not helpful. But this is indeed a better approach than by the ratio of Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: You are right, and I assumed everyone who uses the term "Golden ratio" knows the geometric definition at least. Deleted my comment, because I made a mistake